# Candle in external electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

We put candle in electric field. My question is:
Ions of flame move or ions of air?
It is written that flame heat air molecules and convert them to ions, then positive ions of air heavier than negative ions therefor flame bends in direction of electric field. Is it correct?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495099/candle-in-electric-field

Answer (score 2):

A hydrocarbon flame contains positive ions (molecular radicals, fragments from fuel molecules). These ions are attracted by the negative electrode. As the ions are fairly large, they drag air molecules along with them. So the wind that bends the flame contains both ions and air molecules.

[image]

*Green: positive ions; red: air*

Comment: I read heat of flame separate air molecules to positive and negative ions.then air ions pulled to plates. because positive ions are heavier flame bend to direction of electric field.is it correct?

Comment: Where did these ions come from?H3O+ and ...

Comment: Many of the ions will recombine with electrons, resulting in emission lines that can be identified. An example is shown in the wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_band). They are due to emission of excited molecular radicals that contain carbon from the hydrocarbon fuel.

Comment: As the H3O+ is not mentioned in the example in Wikipedia, I'll remove it from my initial answer